# Maven not using mirror from settings.xml after jdk version change

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a simple java application which prints Hello world. I have mentioned a proxy server in settings.xml which Maven should use while running(running fine in Jenkins).
Previously, I was using jdk7. Now, I changes it to jdk1.8.0_45 and reran the application again(in Jenkins). Now I can see in the log that maven is searching the default repository which is should not be.

Now the error is:

```
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.093s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 07 15:56:36 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: it says `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection timed out: connect` have you read `http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException`?

Comment: Does the log state that it at least tried to access your mirror to download the plugin before it tried to go to maven central? It should mention that right above the snippet you posted.